# What is the function of 可 here: 他可不敢得罪?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

二来，会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴，至于这部影片的投资人，可是一位大人物，他可不敢得罪。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 26. What is the function (and the meaning) of 可 here: 他可不敢得罪? I ask because for me the sentence makes the same sense without it:

他可不敢得罪: He cannot dare to offend

他不敢得罪: He doesn't dare to offend

At least in my feeling in English, the verb "to dare" is enough, it doesn't need the help of "can" to make sense... I can dare... Can is a modal verb while dare is semi-modal. That's why I am perplexed.

Comment: It's an intensifier: "really, indeed". "At all", since it's in the negative.

Answer (score 5):

As Enrico Brasil said in his comment, 可 is a common intensifier.

可:表示强调：他可好了。

他可不敢得罪.
He absolutely doesn't dare offend.
(Maybe he is abnormally afraid of rejection, or maybe he will go back to prison if he is in any way remiss.)

我？失败？我可不这样认为。
Me? Fail? I really don't think so.

这可不好。
That is really bad.

那可不一样。
That is completely different.

Answer (score 3):

This 可 is an adverb used for emphasis (it's a separate definition to the 可 in 可以, 可能, etc.); the Pleco dictionary "GF" gives this definition:

> 用于一般陈述句，表示强调。
> Used in ordinary declarative sentences, expresses emphasis.

It's similar to how 就 in 就是 etc. and 并 in 并不 are used.

As a funny example, I remember one time when one of my Chinese friends was once asked if he's a foreigner, and he replied something like:

> 我**可**不是外国人。
> I'm **certainly** not a foreigner

He's not only not a foreigner, he's local to the area, and in the middle of a conversation in Chinese as a native Chinese speaker, so he was rather surprised by the question.

So maybe a reasonable English translation of the given sentence is:

> ……，他**可**不敢得罪。
> ..., he **certainly** dare not offend.

Another example you might have encountered if you play the game Genshin Impact (原神) is 安柏 saying:

> 我**可**是蒙德城的飞行冠军！  ([video](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1dK411A7B4/))
> I am **indeed** Mondstadt's flying champion.

Answer (score 1):

How to understand "他可不敢得罪?"

First, the sentence uses an inversed word order. The subject is missing. I guess it could be "我" or "你". **得罪** (offend) is the verb. **他** is the object. Besically this sentence means "我不敢得罪他" = "对他, 我不敢得罪".

Second, what is the function of "**可**"?

In affirmative sentences, **可** = **可以**, which means "possible" or "possibly".

In negative sentences, **不可** = **可不** = **不可以**, which means "not possible", "impossible", or "unthinkable ". **可不** is in an even stronger mood. For example,

你不可以去. = You could not go there.

你可不能去. = You must not go there.

Comment: The full passage is "大导演非常着急，一来，耽误了时间，日程就得重新安排；二来，会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴，至于这部影片的投资人，可是一位大人物，他可不敢得罪。" 他 refers to 大导演, not the investor.

Comment: I see. 至于投资人 (一位大人物)，他(大导演)可不敢得罪. "投资人" is the topic (usually object). 他 is the subject. 他不敢得罪投资人. Thanks.